# ng serve of angular before cucumberjs + playwright test execution

Tags: angular, cucumberjs, playwright

We are execution our tests with cucumberjs and playwright.

Is there a way to start angular with ng serve (with test config) before execution of tests and shut application down after tests are finished?

Something like webServer Configuration in PlaywrightTestConfig: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little open ended and there could be many opinionated ways to solve it. Two options are:

1. Use one of the CI integrations as described in their documentation: https://playwright.dev/docs/ci
2. Use the npm package [start-server-and-test](https://github.com/bahmutov/start-server-and-test)

Comment: Thank you. The second plugin works really fine for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extension to the Angular CLI builders, which waits until the ng server is ready and then runs a command. In this case, to run playwright.
That's how Protractor does it. Cypress also follows the same pattern.

There's a module in NPM to achieve that: `@dot-build/serve-and-run-angular`

You can read [this article](https://dev.to/darlanalves/playwright-angular-cli-39ab) for an example.

All it does is to internally start the devServer target that you specified, and once the server is ready, run a shell command.